# Link error while using Qt 4.7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, qt4, linker-errors, qt4.6

I am using Qt 4.7 for VS08 and i am building a http webser, but i am getting some link errors while compiling it and cant figure it out though
here is one of them

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000027) "public: bool __thiscall QBasicAtomicInt::operator== int)const " (??8QBasicAtomicInt@@$$FQBE_NH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QList::free(struct QListData::Data *)" (?free@?$QList@VQString@@@@$$FAAEXPAUData@QListData@@@Z)
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall QCoreApplication::~QCoreApplication(void)" (??1QCoreApplication@@$$FUAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall HttpService::HttpService(int,char * *)" (??0HttpService@@$$FQAE@HPAPAD@Z)

I did included a QBasicAtomicInt header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about qmake or use the [Visual Studio plugin for Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).

Comment: I have actually installed the plug in though...but still cant get rid of the error.

Comment: With the Qt plugin you should set your Qt version including the path and then create a new Qt project via the menu.